# Fortran End of File Unexpected Error

Tags: windows, fortran, gfortran

I'm running a program in Fortran that does a lot of calculations. Basically, it runs a few calculating cycles as many times as there are particles in the experiment.

I have been able to successfully test and obtain output data for 500 000, 1 000 000 and 1 500 000 particles, but as soon as I run the program with more input particles (say, 2 000 000 or 5 000 000), it crashes closer to the end stating an 'End of File' error in on the files it's reading. Reading files mentioned is a necessity for the calculations I'm carrying out and program does this operation in every cycle.

What's concerning me is how is the program able to accurately do all the calculations 1 500 000 times, but not 2 000 000? Is there any limitation in fortran code that makes program unstable while performing extensive calculations?

The fact that the program works for any number of particles below certain amount suggests that everything should be in order. The files are rewinded at the end of read operation and so on. How can I determine the problem?

Thank you.

Update: Okay, I'm attaching the code so people could view it and hope that someone would help me out. This is the second calculating cycle (the first one shows no errors even when counting immense ammounts of particles).

```
    NSTAT = 0
NSTAP = int(NSTATN/10)
NDSTAT = NSTAP         ! Number STAT for visualisation

10 continue

NSTAT=NSTAT+1

x = 50.*sqrt(RNDM(IY))

y  = 0.
z = 1.E-20
ct = 1.                 ! initial state photon
st = sqrt(1.-ct*ct)
cf = 1.
sf = 0.
ves = 1.
E = YNT2001()

    Call FGAMMA()           !  -> calculation of penetration photons

!** zahler
      IF(NSTAT.GE.NDSTAT) GO TO 15
      GO TO 11
 15   PRINT*, NSTAT
      IAWA = NSTAT*100/NSTATN
      WRITE (TEXTW,103) IAWA
      PRINT*, TEXTW                ! print STAT
      NDSTAT=NDSTAT+NSTAP
 11   IF(NSTAT.GE.NSTATN) GO TO 20
      GO TO 10
!** zahler

20    call RESULT                  ! Results of Calculation
```

This part here chooses random starting Energy and processes the calculation as well as showing the progress in output window (zahler). Let's trace the calculation further. FGAMMA:

```
SUBROUTINE FGAMMA()

      COMMON /SOS/   E,X,Y,Z,CT,ST,CF,SF,W
      COMMON /RMX/   Rmax,Rkmax
      COMMON/OTC/    GOTC,WOTC
      COMMON /ktt/   ktot,kcom,kpho,kpar
      COMMON /RES/   VS,VSI,TD
      COMMON /wpp/   Wp
      COMMON /w51/   w511,IP

      VS = 0.
      VSI = 0.

      ktot = 1;kcom = 1;kpho = 1;kpar = 1
      CALL SIG_phots(E,Stots,SSKs,SSFs,SSPs)

      if(ct > 0.) then
      dl = (Rmax - z)/ct
      else
      dl = - z/ct
      endif

      sss = dl*Stots
      WFZ = 1- exp(-sss)                   ! Wes wzaimodeystwiy

      RN = RNDM(IY)
      IF(RN <= 0.) RN=1.E-4
      DLPR = - LOG(1.-RN*WFZ)/Stots               ! probeg of photon

 1    Z=Z+DLPR*CT
      RR=DLPR*ST
      X=X+RR*CF                            ! new coordianats of photon
      Y=Y+RR*SF

100   continue
!*************** para ****************************
If(E > 1.022) then
Wp= SSPs/STOTs*W*WFZ        ! Probabilaty of paar creation
IP = 1
GP = GOTC
GOTC = 0.06

CALL BLAN()              !!!!!!!!!!!!!! WKLAD of effekt

GOTC = GP
endif
!************** compton **************************
      W= SSKs/STOTs*W*WFZ                        ! Probabilaty of Compton creation
IP = 0
      CALL BLPS()                            !!!!!!!!!!!!!!WKLAD Local Estimation
EP = E
      CALL COMKL3(Ep,E)
      IF(E.LT.GOTC) RETURN
                                            !NEXT COLLISIONS
      ktot = 1;kcom = 1;kpho = 1;kpar = 1
      CALL SIG_phots(E,Stots,SSKs,SSFs,SSPs)

      if(ct > 0.) then
      dl = (Rmax - z)/ct
      else
      dl = - z/ct
      endif
      sss = dl*Stots
      WFZ = 1- exp(-sss)                   ! Wes wzaimodeystwiy
      RN = RNDM(IY)
      IF(RN <= 0.) RN=1.E-4
      DLPR = - LOG(1.-RN*WFZ)/Stots

      Z=Z+DLPR*CT
      RR=DLPR*ST
      X=X+RR*CF
      Y=Y+RR*SF
      GO TO 100
END
```

As we can see, there are more subroutines here. I'm providing them as well.

```
SUBROUTINE BLAN()

   COMMON /SOS/   E,X,Y,Z,CT,ST,CF,SF,VES
   COMMON /DET/   XDET,YDET,ZDET
   COMMON /RES/   VS,VSI,TD
   COMMON /OTC/   GOTC,WOTC
   COMMON /A511/  S511s
   COMMON /RMX/   Rmax,Rkmax
   COMMON /ktt/   ktot,kcom,kpho,kpar
   COMMON /wpp/   Wp
   COMMON /w51/   w511,IP

      TW=E
      XW=X
      YW=Y
      ZW=Z
      COSTW=CT         !Memory 1 photon
      SINTW=ST
      COSFW=CF
      SINFW=SF
      VESW=VES
      ves = wp

      XD=XDET-X
      YD=YDET-Y
      ZD=ZDET-Z
      DW = SQRT(XD*XD+YD*YD+ZD*ZD)
      DWW = 1./DW
      AL2=(XDET-X)*DWW
      AM2=(YDET-Y)*DWW
      AN2=(ZDET-Z)*DWW
      if(ZDET > 0.) then
      DWZ = (Rmax-Z)/AN2
      else
      DWZ = -Z/AN2
      endif
!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  RANGE IN MATTER
      CT = AN2
      if(CT > 1. ) CT = 1.
      if(CT < -1.) CT = -1.
      ST = SQRT(1.-CT*CT)
 IF(ST.LE.0.) THEN
      CF = 1.
      SF = 0.
 ELSE
     if(AN2 > 1. ) AN2 = 1.
     if(AN2 < -1.) AN2 = -1.
     CF = AL2/SQRT(1.-AN2*AN2)
     if(CF < -1.) CF =-1.
     if(CF > 1. ) CF = 1.
     WSFK = SQRT(1.-CF*CF)
     SF = AM2/SQRT(1.-AN2*AN2)
     IF(SF > 0.)SF =  WSFK
     IF(SF < 0.)SF = -WSFK
 ENDIF

! FIRST

      RQ=DWZ*S511s
      w511 = EXP(-RQ)*2.
!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  RANGE IN MATTER
      VS = EXP(-RQ)*0.15915*Wp
      VSI=VS*0.511
      TD=0.511

      CALL ANALYS

!!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++     first 0.511
      CT=1.-2.*RNDM(IY)
      ST=sqrt(1.-CT*CT)
      Cf=cfp(Sf)
      CSW=CT
      STW=ST
      CFW=CF
      SFW=SF
      E=0.511
      ves = wp
IP = 0.
CALL GAM_511()
!!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++    second 0.511
      E=0.511
      CT=-CSW
      ST=-STW
      CF=-CFW
      SF=-SFW
      X=XW
      Y=YW
      Z=ZW
      ves = wp
      IP = 0.
CALL GAM_511()

      E=TW
      X=XW
      Y=YW
      Z=ZW
      CT=COSTW                 !Memory 1 photon
      ST=SINTW
      CF=COSFW
      SF=SINFW
      VES=VESW
      kcom = 1
      kpar = 1
      ktot = 1
      RETURN
END
!************************************************************************
SUBROUTINE BLPS()

      COMMON /RES/  VS,VSI,TD
      COMMON /SOS/  T,X,Y,Z,COST,SINT,COSF,SINF,VES
      COMMON /DET/  XDET,YDET,ZDET
      COMMON /OTC/  GOTC,WOTC
      COMMON /ktt/  ktot,kcom,kpho,kpar
      COMMON /UG1/  SINP,COSP,SFK,CFK
      COMMON /w51/  w511,IP
      COMMON /wpp/  Wp
      COMMON /RMX/  Rmax,Rkmax
      parameter    (pi=3.14159,re=2.8179E-13,rek12=0.5*re*re,pire2=pi*re*re)
      parameter    (amc2=0.511,aimc2=1./amc2)


      COSTW=COST
      SINTW=SINT
      COSFW=COSF
      SINFW=SINF
      VESW=VES

      AL1=SINT*COSF
      AM1=SINT*SINF
      AN1=COST
      DW=SQRT((XDET-X)**2+(YDET-Y)**2+(ZDET-Z)**2)
      DWW = 1./DW
      AL2=(XDET-X)*DWW
      AM2=(YDET-Y)*DWW
      AN2=(ZDET-Z)*DWW
      COSK=AL1*AL2+AM1*AM2+AN1*AN2
      AL=T/0.511
      TD=T/(1.+AL*(1.-COSK))
      IF(TD.lt.GOTC) GO TO 12
      W=TD/T

      e0 = T*aimc2
      twoe01 = 2.*e0+1.
      Wl =alog(twoe01)
      compt1 = 2.*pire2*( (1.+e0)/(e0*e0)*( 2.*(1.+e0)/twoe01-&
               Wl/e0 )+Wl/(2.*e0)-(1.+3.*e0)/(twoe01*twoe01))
      dsdo1 = rek12*W*W*(W+1./W-1.+COSK*COSK)                   !Dsigma/Domega/sig_tot -> Compton
      ot_sec = dsdo1/compt1
!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  RANGE IN MATTER
     COST = AN2
     if(COST > 1. ) COST = 1.
     if(COST < -1.) COST = -1.
     SINT = SQRT(1.-COST*COST)
     IF(SINT.LE.0.) THEN
     COSF = 1.
    SINF = 0.
     ELSE
     if(AN2 > 1. ) AN2 = 1.
     if(AN2 < -1.) AN2 = -1.

      COSF = AL2/SQRT(1.-AN2*AN2)
       if(COSF < -1.) COSF =-1.
       if(COSF > 1. ) COSF = 1.
      WSFK = SQRT(1.-COSF*COSF)
      SFK = AM2/SQRT(1.-AN2*AN2)
       IF(SFK > 0.)SINF =  WSFK
       IF(SFK < 0.)SINF = -WSFK
      ENDIF
      ktot = 1;kcom = 0;kpho =0; kpar = 0
! FIRST
      CALL SIG_phots(TD,SZs,TSK,TSF,TPP)
      if(ZDET > 0.) then
      DWZ = (Rmax-Z)/AN2
      else
      DWZ = -Z/AN2
      endif
      RQ=DWZ*SZs
!+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++  RANGE IN MATTER
      IF(RQ.GE.35.)  then
      VS = 0.
      VSI = 0.
      GO TO 12
      endif
IP=0
if(IP==0) then
    VS=VES*ot_sec*EXP(-RQ)
    else
    VS=wp*ot_sec*EXP(-RQ)
endif

    IF(VS.LT.WOTC) then
    VS = 0.
    VSI = 0.
    GO TO 12
    endif
    VSI=VS*TD

      CALL ANALYS

12    COST=COSTW
      SINT=SINTW
      COSF=COSFW
      SINF=SINFW
      VES=VESW
      kcom = 1
      kpar = 1
      ktot = 1
END
!*******************************************************
SUBROUTINE GAM_511()

      COMMON /SOS/   E,X,Y,Z,CT,ST,CF,SF,W
      COMMON /RMX/   Rmax,Rkmax
      COMMON/OTC/    GOTC,WOTC
      COMMON /ktt/   ktot,kcom,kpho,kpar
      COMMON /w51/   w511,IP


      ktot = 1;kcom = 1;kpho = 1;kpar = 0
      CALL SIG_phots(E,Stots,SSKs,SSF,SSPs)

      RN = RNDM(IY)
      IF(RN <= 0.) RN=1.E-4
      RNl = - ALOG(RN)
      DLPR = RNl/Stots

      Z=Z+DLPR*CT
      IF(Z < 0.)      RETURN
      IF(Z > Rmax)    RETURN
      RR=DLPR*ST
      X=X+RR*CF
      Y=Y+RR*SF

100   continue

      RN=RNDM(IY)
      STET=1./STOTs
      IF(RN.LT.SSKs*STET)  GO TO 54       !COMPTON
!*************** photo ***************************
      RETURN
!*************************************************
!************** compton **************************
54    continue
IP = 1.
      CALL BLPS()                             !!!!!!!!!!!!!!WKLAD
EP =E
      CALL COMKL3(Ep,E)
      IF(E.LT.GOTC) RETURN
                                             !NEXT COLLISIONS
!      ktot = 1;kcom = 1;kpho = 1;kpar = 0
      CALL SIG_phots(E,Stots,SSKs,SSFs,SSPs)

      RN = RNDM(IY)
      IF(RN.LE.0.) RN=1.E-4
      RNl = - ALOG(RN)/Stots

      Z=Z+DLPR*CT
      if(z < 0.)      return
      IF(Z > Rmax)    RETURN
      RR=DLPR*ST
      X=X+RR*CF
      Y=Y+RR*SF
      GO TO 100
END

Subroutine SIG_phots(E_ph,Stot,Scom,Spho,Spai)
!******************************************************
! ktot ->  total   if = 1
! kcom ->  Compton if = 1
! kpho ->  Photo   if = 1
! kpar ->  Pair    if = 1
!******************************************************

COMMON /SBTgs/etabls(1000),SFLs(1000),SKKs(1000),SPPs(1000),SGTs(1000)
COMMON /SB/  dem,Emin,deb
COMMON /ktt/ ktot,kcom,kpho,kpar

IF(E_ph.LT.1.) THEN
     i = int((E_ph-Emin)*dem)+1
!print*,E_ph,Emin,dem
!read(*,*)
     DX=E_ph-etabls(I)
     AA=DX/(etabls(I+1)-etabls(I))
     Spai = 0.
     IF(ktot.eq.1)   Stot = SGTs(I)+(SGTs(I+1)-SGTs(I))*AA
     IF(kcom.eq.1)   Scom = SKKs(I)+(SKKs(I+1)-SKKs(I))*AA
     IF(kpho.eq.1)   Spho = SFLs(I)+(SFLs(I+1)-SFLs(I))*AA
     return
ENDIF

     i = int((E_ph-1.)*deb)+200
     DX=E_ph-etabls(I)
     AA=DX/(etabls(I+1)-etabls(I))

     IF(ktot.eq.1)   Stot = SGTs(I)+(SGTs(I+1)-SGTs(I))*AA
     IF(kcom.eq.1)   Scom = SKKs(I)+(SKKs(I+1)-SKKs(I))*AA
     IF(kpho.eq.1)   Spho = SFLs(I)+(SFLs(I+1)-SFLs(I))*AA
     Spai = 0.
     IF(E_ph.gT.1.2) THEN
     IF(kpar.eq.1)   Spai = SPPs(I)+(SPPs(I+1)-SPPs(I))*AA
     ENDIF
     return
END

 SUBROUTINE COMKL3(T,TR)
      COMMON /SOS/ E,X,Y,Z,CT,ST,CF,SF,WW
      COMMON /UG1/ SINTP,COSTP,SINFP,COSFP

      TAU = T*1.9569
      TAUS = TAU
      ab = 1./(1.+2.*TAU)
      A = TAU*ab
      AA = A+TAU
      FA = 1.+2.*TAU+ab
      FAK=FA+2.
      GT=TAU-A

6     CSIS=A+RNDM(IY)*GT
      R1=RNDM(IY)
      ETA=RNDM(IY)*FAK
      FIL=FA-2.*(CSIS-A)

      IF(ETA.GT.FIL) THEN
      CSI=AA-CSIS
      ETA=FAK-ETA
      ELSE
      CSI=CSIS
      ENDIF

       AB=1./TAU-1./CSI
       FKA=TAU/CSI+CSI/TAU+AB*(2.+AB)

      IF(ETA.GT.FKA)  THEN
      GO TO 6
      ELSE
      TR=CSI*0.511
      TAU=CSI
      ENDIF

      COSTP = 1.-1./TAU+1./TAUS
      S = 1.-COSTP*COSTP
      IF(S.lt.0.) S = 0.
      COSFP = CFP(SINFP)

      SINTP=SQRT(S)
      CALL UGOLKY(CT,ST,CF,SF,A1,A2,A3,A4,1)
END

SUBROUTINE COMKL(T)
      COMMON/UG1/  STDOP,CTDOP,SFDOP,CFDOP
      COMMON /SOS/ E,X,Y,Z,CT,ST,CF,SF,WW
      TAU=T*1.9569E0
      TS=T
      TAUS=TAU

1     CONTINUE
      ALFR=TAU*(1.+2.D0*RNDM(iy)*TAU)/(1.+2.*TAU)
      AN=1.0/TAU
      AR=1.0/ALFR
      FF=AN*ALFR+TAU*AR+(AN-AR)*(2.0+AN-AR)
      PRW=RNDM(iy)*(1.0+2.0*TAU+1.0/(1.0+2.0*TAU))
       IF(FF.GT.PRW) THEN
       T=ALFR*0.511
       TAU = ALFR
       ELSE
       GO TO 1
       ENDIF

      COSTGP=1.0-(TAUS-TAU)/(TAU*TAUS)
      S=1.0-COSTGP*COSTGP
      if(s.lt.0.0)S=0.0

        CALL azim(CFDOP,SFDOP)
        CTDOP= COSTGP
        STDOP= SQRT(S)
        L=1
        CALL UGOLKY(CT,ST,CF,SF,A1,A2,A3,A4,L)

END

SUBROUTINE UGOLKY(CTE,STE,CFE,SFE,COST,SINT,COSF,SINF,L)

      COMMON/UG1/  ST,CT,SF,CF

      A1=ST*CF
      COST=CTE*CT-STE*A1
      IF(COST.GT.1.)COST=1.
 if(SQRT(1.-COST*COST)<0.) then
 print*,COST,COST*COST
 read(*,*)
 endif
      SINT=SQRT(1.-COST*COST)
      IF(abs(SINT).GT.1.E-5) GO TO 2
1     SINF=0.
      COSF=1.
      GO TO 3
2     A2=STE*CT+CTE*A1
      A1=ST*SF
      COSF=(A2*CFE-A1*SFE)/SINT
      SINF=(A2*SFE+A1*CFE)/SINT
3     GO TO (4,5),L
4     STE=SINT
      CTE=COST
      SFE=SINF
      CFE=COSF
5     RETURN
END
```

So... is it enough to determine the error in counting vast numbers of particles?

Comment: If you want help debugging your program, please try to shrink your program so that it still reproduces the problem, e.g. only the looping/iterating and reading file. Then post the relevant section of the code together with your question.

Comment: Are you storing the data as you are doing the computations?  If yes, is that in an array or in a file?

Comment: cup, say, I'm calculating X for two million particles. So I count it over and over again two million times and add its value to some other variable that was defined as 0 at the beginning. E.g. Y=Y+X in cycle body at the end. As a result, I simply need (and have) that variable that is a sum of two million calculated values.

Comment: provide some code, these descriptions are pointless

Comment: I've updated my message, please look there for code.

Comment: Too much code.  Common causes of unexpected end of file errors are (i) an attempt to read past the last line of a file and (ii) an attempt to read from a file which doesn't exist (or which was created empty by an immediately preceding carelessly constructed `open` statement). I suggest you look into both of those possibilities.  What, for example, is the name of the file in question ?  And @steabert's advice is still good, shrink your program to a minimal example which still exhibits the problem.

Comment: For a modern code this amount could be comprehensible, but this is a real spaghetti mess with misleading indentation

Comment: Well, this SECOND cycle was not constructed by me but I need to use it in my research, there's no other way. The thing I cannot possibly comprehend is how can program calculate something 1 500 000 times but presents an end of file error when prompted to calculate it 2 000 000 times? If there was an empty file or an attempt to read past the end of file it would show an error earlier, am I wrong?

Comment: You seem to be thinking that your code cannot possibly be wrong despite the evidence that it is.  I think that your mindset is preventing you rolling up your sleeves and debugging.  What investigations have you performed, what use have you made of your debugger, at what line does the program crash ?  There's a limit to how much help you can reasonably expect SO to provide, your question goes well past that.  Too much code, but not enough to compile.  No input data to use.  No indentation or other typographic features to make the code easy to read.  I'd go on if I hadn't run out of room ...

Comment: Mark, I don't expect people to debug instead of me and I didn't provide enough code to compile because I wasn't requested to do so, yet I was asked to provide the relevant code and so I did, but it's not my mistake it's constructed by intervined subroutines and contains misleading indentations. I'm trying to think logically here to determine the source of problem and, as I said, I don't understand how it can be possible that program presents an END OF FILE error while doing 2 million calculations, at the same time carrying out 1,5 million calculations without any errors.

Comment: I've fixed it, the problem was in read(*,*) statement somewhere in the body of the program used for debugging purposes. When prompted to calculate over2000000 particles that statement created an instability in the program, crashing it somewhere along the way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem fixed, it was in read(,) statement somewhere in the body of the program used for debugging purposes.